# How can i use neovim and coc.nvim for develop windows c++ apps on linux

Tags: c++, neovim, coc.nvim, clangd

I develop c++ apps on linux and i use neovim with [coc.nvim](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) and [coc-clangd](https://github.com/clangd/coc-clangd) plugins.
I want to develop an app for windows but i comfort with linux and neovim so i want to use them for it. But i get some include errors with some windows headers (etc. "windows.h").

I use linux only for writing the code and i'll compile the program on windows. How can i prevent this errors and use windows headers with coc.nvim?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i'll compile the program on windows

You can cross-compile it from Linux. It's only marginally more difficult than getting the code completion to work.

1. Get the standard library headers (and libraries, if you want to cross-compile) from MinGW.

   Your package manager might have those, or you can get them from https://winlibs.com/.

   I prefer getting those from MSYS2, and made scripts to automate this (since MSYS2 is otherwise Windows-only):

   ```bash
   git clone https://github.com/holyblackcat/quasi-msys2
   cd quasi-msys2/
   make install _gcc
   ```
2. Figure out the Clang flags needed to cross-compile.

   Unlike GCC, which for every target platform requires a separate compiler distribution, Clang is inherently a cross-compiler. You only need a single Clang distribution to compile for any supported platform.

   Download Clang from your package manager, and point it to the freshly downloaded headers and libraries.

   Following flags work for me: `clang++-14 1.cpp --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --sysroot=/path/to/quasi-msys2/root/mingw64 -fuse-ld=lld-14 -pthread -stdlib=libstdc++ -femulated-tls -rtlib=libgcc`.

   `--target` and `--sysroot` are crucial. The latter needs to point to the files you've downloaded. The remaining flags are less important.

   Running this should produce `a.exe`, runnable with `wine a.exe`.
3. Feed the same flags to Clangd.

   There are [several ways](https://clangd.llvm.org/installation) to set compiler flags for Clangd.

   The easiest one is to create a file named `compile_flags.txt` in your project directory, and put the flags into it, one per line:

   ```bash
   --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32
   --sysroot=/path/to/quasi-msys2/root/mingw64
   -fuse-ld=lld-14
   -pthread
   -stdlib=libstdc++
   -femulated-tls
   -rtlib=libgcc
   ```

   Then Clangd should do the right thing for any source files in this directory.

---

Apparently, my Quasi-MSYS2 can somewhat automate this.

After running the commands above (`make install _gcc` and others), run `make env/shell.sh`, and run your editor from this shell.

Replace `compiler_flags.txt` with `compiler_commands.json` with following contents:

```
[
    {
        "directory": "/your/sources",
        "file": "/your/sources/1.cpp",
        "command": "win-clang++ 1.cpp"
    }
]
```

Where `win-clang++` is a Clang wrapper I ship, which automatically adds the flags I listed above.

Configure your editor to add following flag to Clangd: `--query-driver=/path/to/win-clang++` (use `which win-clang++` from quasi-msys2 shell to get the full path).

This makes Clangd obtain the right flags automatically from this wrapper.

Comment: firstly, thanks for your answer.
i tried compile my code with the flags that you write, i got this error:
"clang-14: error: invalid linker name in argument '-fuse-ld=lld-14'". 
when i remove this flag, it compiled successfully. but when i try run the .exe file on windows, i get this error: "libstdc++-6.dll not found"

Comment: @g3n1u5 *"invalid linker name in argument"* LLD needs to be installed separately for it to work. Depending on how it's named, you might need to spell it as just `-fuse-ld=lld`. But if the stock linker works (if everything works without this flag), you can just skip it.

Comment: @g3n1u5 *"libstdc++-6.dll not found"* Copy this file and place it next to your .exe. Quasi-MSYS2 installs it to `quasi-msys2/root/mingw64/bin`. Alternatively, add `-static` to statically link everything.

Comment: .exe runs succcesfully. i write the flags to compile_flags.txt file but then, clangd can't found the iostream file. And shows error for it on neovim :(

Comment: @g3n1u5 Can you share Clangd logs? Not sure where neovim puts those.

Comment: oh, i just enter a wrong path to compile_flags.txt for --sysroot flag. i fixed that and the problem solved now. thanks a lot for your answers.